# Kendo UI Grid View Doesn't re-bind data- attributes

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo-UI's Grid along with the knockout-kendo scripts and I've come across a problem that I think I'm missing something silly for.

I have a few links posted in one of the grid columns, and in that I'm using knockout to set some of the attributes including a data- attribute as so:

`<a class="copyBooking" data-bind="attr: { 'data-bookingid': BookingId }">Copy</a>`

I also have a small piece of Javascript that is set to run when the link is clicked:

```
$(".copyBooking").click(function(){
var bookingId = $(this).data("bookingid");
//code to access a function via ajax'
});
```

All seems fine on the initial load as the code within the Javascript runs and my alert comes back with the expected results. However, when I change pages the in Kendo Grid (I have my data paged to only show 10 results at a time) something stops the Javascript from functioning.

According to the HTML generated in Firebug or it's equivalent in Chrome, the data- attribute is set correctly in the HTML, so I'm no sure if the `.click` isn't firing correctly or if the data- attribute itself isn't being picked up correctly.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As the element doesn't exist after you page through your grid. You need to have this function run on the databound event so that after the grid is re-rendered it will be applied to the 'new' dom element.

The other option would be to extend your knockout model of your rows with a function and click-bind to that.